# Not able to render with graphics card

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

I was rendering a project and noticed that my GPU is not taking any load. Most of the time it stays at around 6% and momentarily spikes to 100%. I have a GeForce 1650 Super and I7-10700F. I am really new to rendering with a GPU since I have just upgraded. Any help will be awesome.

Render Settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Windows Task Manager doesn't show CUDA utilization by default (which is what Cycles uses). To have that show up, click on the "3D" above the graph and choose "Cuda" in the drop down that pops up. It will then show correct utilization.

Comment: I did what you said and the result is about the same, CUDA utilization is 0 most of the time but for a split second spikes to 100%(I have included the screenshot in the answer). Also, I am rendering at optix, is it okay to render at optix with my GPU. Is everything alright and I am just overthinking things?

Comment: Compare render time cpu vs GPU vs GPU&cpu. If with gpu is lower it means you are using gpu